# How this example works? (Book's example of gets function)

Tags: c, string, function

Specifically at the while loop

1. What variable is feeding that getchar() function?if is 's' where it is expressed?
2. Does this function is a good use? I see problems on various "reading" functions like gets(), fgets() or scanf(). Does this one would give problems like the others?

   ```
   char * mygets(char *s) {
     int i = 0, ch;
     while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
       s[i++] = ch;
     s[i] = '\0';
     return s;
   }

   main() {
     char input[21];
     printf("type anything:\n");
     mygets(input);
     printf("output: %s\n", input);
   }
   ```

Comment: "Does this function is a good use?" --> No, as it is subject to buffer overrun.  There are at least 5  short-comings.  Yet it would be good if OP first had posted what the answers appeared to be.  Else it looks like SO doing OP's homework.

Comment: @chux OP? well i believe s is feeding the getchar() function but i cant see where this information are declared to it. No, that is not a homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the getchar(3) or gets(3) functions, the input is being read from the process standard input.

> The getchar() function is equivalent to getc(stdin).

Since gets reads one character at a time, you would need to count the characters read, and ensure that you do not 'walk off the end of available space'. Which means you need to pass the 'size' of s.

```
char*
mygets(char *s) {
    //is s a valid pointer to memory?
    //how much space is available in s?
    int i = 0, ch;
    //what is the maximum value of an int?
    //what happens when i++ exceeds MAX_INT?
    //does -1 make sense?
    //getchar(3) can return EOF
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
        s[i++] = ch;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

Try something like this instead. Count the characters read, check that you do not run off the end of the passed buffer, and

```
char*
mygets(char* s, const size_t size) {
    if( !s ) return s; //error, null pointer passed
    size_t count=0;
    char* sp = s;
    int ch;
    for( ; (count<size) && ((ch = getchar()) != EOF); ) {
        ++count; //count each character read, but not EOF
        if( (*sp++ = ch) == '\n' ) break; //store characters read, check for newline
    }
    *sp = '\0'; //null terminate s
    return s;
}
```

You should only pass sane values for size, and sane values for s (valid char buffers of *at least* size). Example usage:

```
char buffer[999];
mygets(buffer, 999); //or mygets(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Answer (score 0):

1) getchar() gets one character as it is typed....so it 'waits' for you to type...one character on the keyboard..

2) This is a basic function, there are much more optimal and advanced functions to do these things with characters...but understanding what's happening here is VERY important if you want to code properly..

Cheers...

Comment: how does getchar() recognizes the s parameter should feed it?